# Center content of inline-block div elements

Tags: html, css, alignment

I try to do something like this in CSS/HTML:

[image: example]

Each “Box” should be a link to the details of the error. 
The text and the red div inside of the box should be horizontally centered, as shown in the image.

Here is my code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/musium/2mxud8uk/1/)

```
.outerDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #c3c3c3;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.innerDiv {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.errorLabel {    
    background-color: #a90329;
    display: inline;
    padding: .2em .6em .3em;
    font-size: 75%;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: .25em;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Edit:** 
After the answer of [Fabrizio Calderan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098851/fabrizio-calderan)

If detected two small issue.

- When the text of the label is very short it gets displayed on the same line as the text does.
- When the text of the label is very long or contains as line break, the label doesn’t look very good.

[New JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/musium/z7hL3any/)

I was able to fix the first issue by turning the label into a block element.
Now I’m looking for a way to make sure that all label have the same space to the bottom border.
(It should look like the image, and not like the fiddle)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/musium/g6p0wg1j/)

```
.outerDiv {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #c3c3c3;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.errorLabel {
  display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-bottom:7px;
    width:84%;
    background-color: #a90329;
    padding: .2em .6em .3em;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: .25em;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 700;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add a line-height to the inner div, e.g. `line-height: 50px;` and  `text-align: center` to the outer div

http://jsfiddle.net/2mxud8uk/3/

```
.outerDiv {
    text-align: center;
    ...
}

.innerDiv {
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 50%;
    ... 
}
```

---

Result

[image]

Comment: Cool, and how can I center the label horizontally?

Comment: Ah after the update everything is centered nicely. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @musium If its perfect then take efforts to mark it as accapted. :D

Comment: @Ganesh Salunkhe I will accept this as the correct solution…in 1 minute (stackoverflow won’t let me accept it yet)

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan I’ve detected two small issues in your solution and was not able to fix them. Can you take a look at it? Details are in the original questions.